# Two struts2 webapps fail to start together

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat, struts2, web-applications

I have problems getting two different struts2 webapps to start together in tomcat. But each of the webapps start correctly when placed independently inside webapps folder of tomcat.

I get the following in catalina.out logs-

SEVERE: Error filterStart
Aug 13, 2009 3:17:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/admin] startup failed due to previous errors

Environment- Java1.6, Tomcat6, Struts2.1.6, FC10

The webapps are "admin" and "user". Both of these webapps contain struts2 jars inside their WEB-INF/lib directory respectively.

web.xml contains the following in both the webapps-

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

A point to note that always the "admin" webapp fails to load with the above error. If I remove the "user" webapp from webapps folder, "admin" webapp comes up just fine.

I have also observed one more thing w.r.t struts2 filter in web.xml- If I remove the struts2 filter from web.xml in one of the webapps, BOTH the webapps start without any errors in the logs (but of course I won't be able to use struts in the webapp where the filter is removed).

I have also tried moving the struts2 jar to tomcat lib and removing them from individual webapps, but same problem exists..

Any ideas what is causing this problem?

**Updates:** This strangely works fine on Ubuntu OS. But the problem persists on FC10 and OpenSolaris.

Comment: Do you have a bit more logging information, preferably at DEBUG level or something like that? The problem looks a bit like a classpath problem, or maybe log4j problem if you're using that but from this context it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had enabled Struts2 debug logs and did not have any useful information. Now I have enabled the tomcat debug logs to see if it gives me some useful information.

Yes I am using log4j in both the webapps. Can you please elaborate why you speculate it may be a log4j problem?

Comment: Is there anything else in your log files?   Some times the problem can be related to an error thrown earlier in the start up.  We have several Struts 2 apps, about 8 per instance over 3 tomcat instances and they all work fine.  Try trouble shooting a little more and post your results.

Comment: I just had another thought, could naming the app 'admin' interfere with tomcats admin application?  I know you have it working on one tomcat install but maybe the admin app was installed on the tomcat server you are deploying to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks alzoid, extraneon and Peter.

I had overlooked an exception coming up on localhost..log file. I thought I had redirected all the struts log to a different log file but had overlooked mentioning the opensymphony package in the log4j properties file.

Coming to original problem- there was a class loader issue with xerces-impl jar and some other jar file belonging to struts2. So when I removed the xerces-impl jar from the WEB-INF/lib directories in both apps, it started worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using Spring and using this listener class in web.xml:

org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener

See the documentation of the Spring [Log4jWebConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/Log4jWebConfigurer.html), which says you need unique "web app root" properties defined per web-app, so I had to have a section like this in each web.xml:

```
<!-- used by Log4jConfigListener -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>myappname.root</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Are you using Spring ?  If not hope this gives you some clues, I don't know much about Struts2 maybe it does something similar.  Do let me know how it goes !

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not using Spring framework. But, you might have pointed me in the right direction- log4j. I even tried removing log4j.properties and log4j jars from both the web applications to eliminate the log4j from the equation, but the result was same as before..it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem while launching two struts2 Maven apps on the same server. The `xerces` lib was the problem so we did add `xalan` in the `pom.xml` dependencies and everything worked fine:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```